# usage of for in how long are you in town for?

Tags: prepositions

What's the difference between these two sentences?

how long are you in town for?
how long are you in town?

what's usage of **for** ?

Comment: The sentence "How long are you in town for?" can be rearranged to "For what length of time are you in town". I'm not sure if this helps, but it seemed relevant.

Comment: "_For_" is superfluous. But the use of superfluous prepositions is  common (especially in spoken language). For example: _'Where are you going (to)?', 'Where did you get  that (from)?', 'He jumped off (of) the desk.', 'She met (with) her sister for lunch.'_

Comment: And the horribly ubiquitous "where we are at".